# Dataframe column when converting to pandas datetime format results in NaT

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, nat

I read a csv file and try to convert my data frame column 'Date'  to pandas.to_datetime format but it results in NaT. I need the date column should be converted to date format 'year-month-date'

Code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce', format= '%Y-%m-%d')
```

[image]

### output with NaT:

[image]

Comment: `format='%d-%m-%Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself. The format option requires the current format of the dataframe 'Date' column not the expected 'Date' format. I have given the expected format as `format= '%Y-%m-%d'` and changed to the current format of the date and it works.

### Wrong code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce', format= '%Y-%m-%d')
```

### Right code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce', format= '%d-%m-%Y')
```